# 'INSERT INTO' does not insert data to my sql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I used wamp server to browse the database , I started connection with database from nodejs express server
When I wrote insert query there is no error but when I browse the table the added row has empty values .
this is my query code

```
app.post('/new_sess_mouse',function(req,res ){
  var sess_name = req.body.sess_name ,
      sess_id = req.session.id ,
      email = req.session.email ;
var sql = "INSERT INTO ?? SET ?? = ? AND ?? = ? AND ?? = ? ";
     var inserts = ['sessions', 'sess_name' , sess_name ,'sess_id',sess_id ,'email' , email ];
            sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
                 console.log(sql);

  connection.query( sql , function( err , results ){
     if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
     }
     else {
       //connection.destroy();
       console.log('succes');
     }


}); });
```

When I printout the results

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 3,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. Please tag appropriate RDBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong `INSERT` statement format.

You can :

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO ?? ( ??, ??, ??) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
     var inserts = ['sessions', 'sess_name' , 'sess_id', 'email', sess_name , sess_id  , email ];
```

or:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO ?? SET ?? = ? , ?? = ? , ?? = ? ";
     var inserts = ['sessions', 'sess_name' , sess_name ,'sess_id',sess_id ,'email' , email ];
```